# Javascript Canvas и CSS цвета

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, цвета

На сайте мне необходима функция цветовой пипетки,
то есть возможность скопировать цвет пикселя, который находится под курсором.

Для этого я использую canvas и функцию `ctx.getImageData` и получаю массив с нужными цветами `rgba`.

С помощью этого массива можно повторить цвет, в рамках самого Canvas, 
но если попытаться применить этот цвет на стили CSS, то цвет будет другой.

Как я понимаю, между цветовой схемой Canvas и CSS существуют различия.
Как построить JavaScript-функцию, которая бы устраняла эти различия?

UPD: я создал [небольшой пример](https://jsfiddle.net/d3zvggaw/).

Там можно увидеть три элемента — широкий `div`, с цветом `rgb(36,43,51)`,
внутри которого находится элемент Canvas, на котором размещено изображение, состоящее из фона такого же цвета и белой полосы слева,
и ниже него элемент `img` с тем же содержимым.

Вы не увидите разницы между цветами `div` и `img`, потому что они одни и те же.

Но изображение, отображаемое внутри Canvas имеет совсем другой цвет и заметно выделяется на общем фоне.

Как я понимаю, использование функции `ctx.getImageData` показывает правильные цвета и для CSS, и для Canvas, но проблема в том, что все цвета внутри тега `canvas` искажаются.

Comment: вопрос полезный ...удалять незя....

Comment: я не вижу никаких отличий)

Comment: Если бы вы выложили свой код сюда, а не на jsfiddle.net, то вам бы уже давно помогли. Многие не переходят по таким ссылкам так как jsfiddle.net распространяет вирусы. По крайней мере sitecheck.sucuri.net так говорит. Лично я не хожу по таким ссылкам.

Comment: что у Canvas, что у image цвет один и тот же - RGB(36,43,51).

Answer (score 3):

Цветовые схемы не должны отличаться, если вы все делаете верно, приведу рабочий пример:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_id'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  base_image = new Image();
//Изображение в base64 чтобы небыло ошибок с cross origin при вызове getImageData
base_image.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
base_image.onload = () => {
canvas.width = base_image.width;
canvas.height = base_image.height;
ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
}


//При наведении мышки на канвас будем менять цвет у DIV блока
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {

  let x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
    y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop,
    imgData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;


  document.querySelector('#color_div').style.backgroundColor = `rgba(${imgData[0]}, ${imgData[1]}, ${imgData[2]}, 1)`;
});
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; background: rgb(36,43,51);">
  <div style="margin:auto; width: 50%;">
    <canvas id="canvas_id" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid red"></canvas>

    <div id="color_div" style="width:200px; height:200px;">color</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Все ровно так, как вы и описывали, в момент наведения мышки мы высчитываем ее x\y координаты относительно `canvas`, далее получаем по этим координатам `imageData` и получаем 4 значения соответствующих red,green,blue,aplha.